# Conditional distribution and correlation

Tags: correlation, conditional-probability

Hi I have a question about the conditional distribution.

Suppose that there are two random variable called X and Y.
Here, we assume that the distribution of Y depends on X, that is, the conditional distribution is exist.
In this case, can we say that Y is correlated with X?

Thank you for your time spent to read this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Correlation" should refer to "linear correlation", which exists when covariance is not zero. In that sense, no, the existence of dependence does not imply correlation - it may be the case that two variables are dependent (and so there is a distinct conditional distribution) but their covariance is zero.

I just note that sometimes the term "correlation" is used in a more general sense, as a synonym for "dependence", which is not useful and can be confusing and best be avoided.

Comment: For an example of dependence with zero covariance, consider the letter X.